How do I delete all folders with a similar name that do not contain large files on linux commandline?
On my linux server for my media library I used a function to change show season names to have a leading zero when needed, so "Season 1" would be Season 01" and so on. The problem is that some metadata did not get deleted due to a permissions issue, so now almost all folders have both "Season x" folders and "Season 0x" folders.
The unwanted folders only contain an empty metadata folder and a thumbnail image, while the wanted folders will contain one or more video files and srt and nfo files
what would be the simplest way to recursively look into every show folder and delete all "Season*" folders that do not contain videos? is it easier to check the folder size on disk or for the presence of files that must be kept?

Do thumbnail images get generated automatically? Do their names follow some specific pattern? If so, an easy way may be to remove all thumbnails, then remove empty directories, finally let (wanted) thumbnail images be generated again over time. Not necessarily an optimal solution, but simple. Is it acceptable? What have you tried?
